# Unable to sort a Swift array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to sort my `contacts` array by `severity`

```
    var contacts: [Contact]?   

    if let customer = CoreDataAccess.sharedInstance.getSavedCustomer() {
       //Cast from NSSet to [Contact]        
       self.contacts = customer.contacts.allObjects as? [Contact]
       self.contacts!.sort({$0.severity < $1.severity}) //error
    }
```

The compiler errors out at the marked line with the following message:

```
Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because this exact same thing worked in another file. If it helps to explain, the above code crashes when running on the WatchKit interface, but not when used in iOS.

EDIT: severity is an `NSNumber`

Comment: Try reproducing the problem in a dummy project. If it's possible, file a bug report at Apple Bug Reporter.

Comment: How is `severity` declared? What type does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast the first argument explicit to `NSNumber` and use the `compare:` method (I tested it in a Playground)

```
var contacts: [Contact]?
if let customer = CoreDataAccess.sharedInstance.getSavedCustomer() {
    //Cast from NSSet to [Contact]
    self.contacts = customer.contacts.allObjects as? [Contact]
    self.contacts!.sort { ($0.severity as NSNumber).compare($1.severity) == .orderedAscending }
}
```

It's even more efficient to declare the relationship as native Swift set `Set<Contact>` and the attribute as `Int`, this avoids to call `allObjects` and the type casts. And declare `contacts` as non-optional empty array.

```
var contacts = [Contact]()
if let customer = CoreDataAccess.sharedInstance.getSavedCustomer() {
    self.contacts = customer.contacts.sorted { $0.severity < $1.severity }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Casting `NSNumber` to `Int` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the property of Contact "severity" !

The type of "severity" is your custom type, and it's not implement compare operator like "<"

Since severity is NSNumber
We can do this

```
func <(lhs: NSNumber, rhs: NSNumber) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
func >(lhs: NSNumber, rhs: NSNumber) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
func ==(lhs: NSNumber, rhs: NSNumber) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
}
```

then the code will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var contacts: [Contact]?   
if let customer = CoreDataAccess.sharedInstance.getSavedCustomer() {
   //Cast from NSSet to [Contact]        
   self.contacts = customer.contacts.allObjects as? [Contact]
   self.contacts!.sort {
       $0.severity < $1.severity
   }
}
```